# existe algum banco de dados em que eu possa guardar ficheiros .mp3

Tags: php

Boas. a minha pergunta é se existe algum banco de dados em que eu possa utilizar em que guarde 
ficheiros .mp3 (php)

Comment: Porque quer armazenar isso dentro do BD? Parece desperdício e excessivo... Pode descrever melhor seu objetivo e necessidades?

Comment: Usa uma cloud para guardar os ficheiros... Amazon por exemplo. Depois é só usar a API REST da Amazon para gerênciar os ficheiros.

Comment: Bem, você pode usar a maioria dos bancos para armazenar qualquer tipo de arquivo com o tipo `blob` (ou binário), porém isso não é recomendado.

Comment: Se o aquivo for muito grande pode usar o campo longblob eu só não sei se e possível executar o aquivo mp3 de dentro do db

Comment: mas eu quero trabalhar numa aplicação que tenha uma base de dados 'online'

Answer (score 3):

Sim, você pode armazenar como o tipo [BLOB](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLOB), porém em geral é melhor armazenar em uma pasta da própria aplicação, exceto em casos específicos, por uma questão de [performance](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2GNX_7.2.1/com.ibm.tivoli.tpm.ref.doc/tables/rdbt_columndata.html?lang=pt-br), pois este tipo é muito custoso para o banco de dados.